# PHP MySql Progress Bar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, exp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Progress bar layout using CSS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865825/progress-bar-layout-using-css-and-html)

I'm making a game that involves energy, EXP, level, missions, etc. Well, When you do missions it costs energy and you recieve cash and EXP once you do a mission. Well, it requires EXP to level up. Leveling up works, but I'm wanting to add a progress bar to show how close you are to level up. An example is Exp: 26,175/27,100. Each time you level the max_exp raises up 250, but was wanting a bar behind the text to show how close they are to level up instead of just seeing text. Here's the leveling coding below..

```
<?php
if ($exp >= $max_exp)
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET level=(level + 1) , max_exp=(max_exp + 250) WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($exp >= $max_exp)
        echo '';
    }
    else
    {
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL, it would seem. If you have the numbers already, you just need to visually style them using HTML/CSS.

Comment: Well, I'm not using a percentage.. I'm using larger numbers that change frequently once you rank up. So kinda confused on how to do this.

Comment: *Math.* `next_level = 750, current_points = 523`, calculate what percentage 523 of 750 is. I'll leave this exercise up to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can echo your ratio as inline css.

An example:

css:

```
div#value
{
    display: block; 
    z-index: 2;
    height: 10px;
}
```

php/html:

```
$value = 35;

//this line will give you "width: 35%"
<div id="value" style="width:<?php echo $value; ?>%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just an HTML/CSS issue: make a table with just one row and TWO column (say one fullgreen, one white), then move the width ratio of the two columns according to your value

Comment: I get what you mean, but how would you move the width ratio with the numbers from the database?

Comment: <table><tr><td width="90%">column1</td><td width="10%">column2</td></tr></table>